# Accessing jena fuseki-server hosted on AWS EC2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, fuseki

I am working on a semantic web project. I use :

- a fuseki-server to host data and answer SPARQL queries
- a java program I wrote using Jena to populate the fuseki-server
- an html/css/javascript front-end to query the fuseki-server and show the results

Everything was working perfectly when hosted on my computer and accessed by localhost:3030 which is the fuseki-server port number. I also tried to host my front-end on github pages which was accessing the fuseki-server through a Ngrok tunnel, and it worked.

The limitation was that my computer needed to be running the server, so it wasn't accessible everytime.

So my team gave me a AWS access and I created an EC2 instance (the lowest possible). I succeeded at running a fuseki-server on this instance, but I can't push my data from my java program to the server (wait forever without timeout) nor read the answer to a request from the front-end (timeout after 1 minute).

I can run my java-program from the EC2 instance and it populates the fuseki-server, but it doesn't resolve my problem for the front-end (I think I can't host it in EC2 ?).

It is my first post here. If someone have an idea, I would be enjoyed to hear it.

Comment: did you open up any necessary ports in the firewall? timing out in both directions suggests not.

Comment: I have open "SSH" TCP 22 to everyone (0.0.0.0/0) and "Custom TCP Rule" TCP 3030 to everyone.
I also tried to open "All traffic" All 0 - 65535 to everyone, but as it didn't solved my problem, I removed it.

But I not used to this protocol things, so maybe my problem comes from this, but I don't know at all what to do.

Comment: It sounds like you opened the ports in the security group. Did you also open them in the firewall software on the server?

Comment: Yes, I opened them in the security group. I think that the needed ports are automatically opened on the fuseki-server as I have no control over it ?
I resolved my problem anyway, I had to prepend "http://" to the DNS in both the java program and the front-end.
I feel dumb, but I didn't know I had to do this.
Thanks for your help Mark !